# Kill a Daemon Thread Whilst the Script is still Running

Tags: python, multithreading

My python script creates alot of threads, they are all daemon threads, I find that I get an error saying "out of memory".

**How do I kill a daemon thread whilst my script/application is running?**

I understand the concept of daemon threads, that they destroy themselves when my process(script or application) closes/finishes. But I want to kill some of my daemon threads whilst my script is still running to avoid the "out of memory" error.

Will my thread below kill itself when there are no more tasks in the queue?

```
class ParsePageThread(threading.Thread):
    THREAD_NUM = 0

    def __init__(self, _queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue       = _queue

    def run(self):
        while(True):
            try:
                url = self.queue.get()
            except Queue.Empty,e:
                return # WILL this kill the thread?
            finally:
                self.queue.task_done()
```

Comment: This sounds like you're doing the wrong thing. Isn't it better to not start a thread if you may use up all your memory rather than killing random ones?

Comment: you might benefit from higher abstraction level such as [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) (reuse threads to do the work instead of creating a new one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer your second question first because it is easier. Yes, returning from the run method will indeed stop the thread. A detailed explanation is [threading: Thread Objects](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#thread-objects) doc.

To stop a thread that is running before it's natural completion you have to get a little more creative. There is no direct kill method on a thread object. What you need to do is use a shared variable to define the state of the thread.

```
alive = True

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run():
        while(alive):
            #do work here
```

In some other piece of code, when you detect a condition for stopping that thread, the other thread simply sets alive to False:

```
alive = False
```

This is a simple example, I'll leave it to you to scale to multiple threads.

### DANGER

This example works because reading and setting a boolean variable are *atomic* actions in python because of the Global Interpreter Lock. [Here](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) is an excellent tutorial for lower level python threading. You should stick to using the Queue object because that's exactly what it's for.

If you do anything more than reading and setting simple variables from multiple threads you should use [Locks](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#lock-objects) or alternatively [Reentrant Locks](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#rlock-objects) depending on your design and needs. Even something as simple as a compare and swap without a lock can cause problems in your program that are very difficult to debug.

Another piece of advice for python multithreading is to never do any significant work in the interpreter thread. It should setup and start all the other threads and then sleep or wait on a [condition object](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#condition-objects) until the program exits. The reason for this is no other python thread can receive operating system [signals](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html). This means that no other thread can deal with `Ctrl+C` aka `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions. It can be a good practice to have the main thread handle the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception and then set all the alive variables to False so you can exit your program quickly. This is especially helpful while developing so you don't have to constantly kill things when you make a mistake.

Comment: It is not clear that `RLock` is even better: [We really mean what we're saying. Really, really. Recursive mutexes are really bad and they really do hide serious bugs.](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.programming.threads/msg/d835f2f6ef8aed99)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Those are good points and I agree that RLocks are not necessarily better. They can be more practical and make interface design simpler. Such that you don't have to specify different interfaces for when you hold or do not hold a lock. In Python especially you're not really gaining any speed by making your code multithreaded because of the GIL. In almost all cases you're actually making it slower by adding locking overhead, so I try to avoid threads. I've found that when I have to do multithreading in Python, (usually because of external libraries) the RLock is more convenient.

Comment: Thats a really good idea, however, i'm running into a more interesting problem... the thread will sometimes hang while attempting to establish tty session with remote server, so I won't be able to use an "alive" flag. Is there any other way of killing the thread?